# easily getting the value ("active") a database entry represents rather than the database entry ("2") itself

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4

I am attempting to show a member's current status, e.g., provisional, active, or retired, which is designated in the database as "1", "2", "3" in a page view.
Here's my code:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %> #at the top of the page
<% unless @user.member_status.blank? %> #later in the body of the page
<div>Member status: <%= @user.member_status %> </div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

The code is correctly returning a number.  Is there a way to easily return a value, e.g., Active, without writing a lot of code, e.g., if "1", return "Provisional", elsif "2", return "Active", etc.

If I do need to write that sort of if / then code, can I somehow put it in the model, rather than every view its used in?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare `member_status` as an enum attribute. Example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum member_status: { provisional: 1, active: 2 }
end
```

More info: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: That works; thank you!  Now, how do I get the first letter capitalized, e.g., Provisional?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Case statement.

```
<% case @user.member_status %>
<% when 1 %>
  <%= "Provisional" %>
<% when 2 %>
  <%= "Active" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is a simple hash:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  STATUSES = {1: 'Provisional', 2: 'Active'}

  def display_status
    STATUSES[member_status]
  end
end
```